# CiviMail tracking URL 404, missing part of path

Tags: email

When CiviMail click tracking is enabled, the redirect url is missing part of the path (specifically "civicrm"). For example:

https://wp.example.com/mailing/url/?u=45092&qid=7749314 should be
https://wp.example.com/civicrm/mailing/url/?u=45092&qid=7749314

The CiviCRM Resource URL path appears correct:
https://wp.example.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm

CiviCRM 5.36.1 / WordPress 5.8.1

Tracking worked before. It seems like a path or permission issue, but I can't find anything.

Any ideas or a place in the code I could str_replace() the URL?

/* ************ */
/* EDITED       */

All the dynamically created mail links are not working, including tokens. I'm sending Scheduled mail now with link tracking off, but realized the optout wasn't working. (Open tracking is working.)

I made a temporary workaround by creating the directory "mailing" containing "optout", "view" and "url" directories. In each, I put an index.php file that updates the URL and redirects using header().